# No Scroller For JList

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jscrollpane, jlist

In my swing application, I set a `Vector` as data to JList. JList is resizable (vertical and horizontal). Number of viewable items is 8. When data is set morethan 8 items to the JList, the Scroller is not visible and to see the rest of items, JList should be pull down. Is there any way to get this JScroller ?

I use Netbeans IDE 7.2  I checked the JScrollerPane's properties. It has `default` values for horizontal and vertical scroll bars.

Here is JScrollPane and JList codes which NetBeans has created.
JScrollPane
`jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();`

This is JList

```
jList1 = new javax.swing.JList();    
jList1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(##, ##, ##));    
jList1.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.LineBorder(new java.awt.Color(##, ##, ##), 1, true));    
jList1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 10)); // NOI18N    
jList1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(##, ##, ##));      

jList1.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);    
jList1.setCellRenderer(new CellRendererManager());    
jList1.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(30, 80));    
jList1.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(30, 80));    
jList1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(30, 80));    
jList1.setValueIsAdjusting(true);    
jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jList1);
```

`

Comment: There are a lot of unknowns still for us -- how are you adding this JScrollPane to the GUI, what layout is used? You're not setting the size of the JList directly via `setSize(...)` or indirectly via `setPreferredSize(...)` are you? Please tell us and show us more.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels. Thanks for your attention. JScrollPane lays on `FreeDesign` layout which shows in NetBeans IDE. JScrollPane has not been set any size.But the JList has set a dimension(30,80)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You state:

> JScrollPane lays on FreeDesign layout which shows in NetBeans IDE. JScrollPane has not been set any size.But the JList has set a dimension(30,80)

There's your problem -- you're setting the Dimension of the JList which prevents it's view from expanding, even if it is held by a JScrollPane.

Solution: don't do this. Read up on and use the various layout managers so that they and your component's innate preferred sizes do all the sizing and heavy lifting for you.

Comment: **YOU ARE GENIUS. SUPER PERFECT !!!!. Thank you sooo much.** It solved. The problem was there. I passed `null` as the dimenstion.(I found no way to remove the setting the setPreferredSize() in NB IDE.) Any way it works as I expected. Once again Thank you very much :D

Comment: _I found no way to remove the setting the setPreferredSize() in NB IDE_ if a tools blocks your path, don't use it ;-)

Comment: @AashMaharoon to "reset" a property in NB, right click the property and select "Restore Default Value".  This will essentially remove any code it has generated for this property and use what ever the component uses by default